# Laravel get Json data from url and Print

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am new with JavaScript. Trying to get Json data from a url and and show it on the page. The problem is when I try to print them it shows output like this `[object Object].` Here is my code.

Controller:

```
public function get_info()
    {
      $item = SuraList::findOrFail(3);
      return response()->json(['item'=> $item]);
    }
```

HTML:

```
<section class="content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="box-body">
        <button class="btn btn-info get-info-btn">Get info</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="show">

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Script:

```
  var test = document.querySelector(".get-info-btn");
  test.addEventListener('click',getInfo);

  function getInfo()
  {
    $.getJSON('/get-info', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var show = document.querySelector(".show");
    show.innerText = data;
});
  }
```

Console:

[image]

I can see the returned Json data in the console. How do I parse this data? I tried many times but ended up with errors.

Comment: Where is your code that parses (or attempts to parse) the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON.[stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)(obj).

In your case, this would return

`"{"item":{"created_at":null, "id":3, [and so on]}"`